# Integrating My Zend Framework Application with Wordpress and having one Login

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework, content-management-system

I am developing a ZF application and I am using wordpress as the CMS.  The problem I have is I have two logins right now one for my application and one for wordpress.  Is there a way that I can have the user login to my application and pass to wordpress the users authentication so that the user does not have to login to wordpress also?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a blog post](http://www.krotscheck.net/2009/05/16/bootstrapping-a-startup-zend-and-wordpress-auth-integration.html) that goes over the process exhaustively. Although slightly older, it should point you in the right direction. I came across it while attempting (unsuccessfully) the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

My blog post about creating a single login when integrating wordpress into an admin area may help you out.

http://www.robjstanley.com/zend-framework-wordpress-single-admin-login/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.